# Deleting a file from Git repo

Tags: git, github

Lets say I had the following files on my local machine's repo:

```
index.php
home.php
text.php
```

I committed the all changes and the Github repo (`origin`) was an exact replica of my this local machine's repo.

Next, I renamed `text.php` to `unit_test.php`. I committed it. So, now my Github repo has 4 files: `index.php`, `home.php` `test.php` & `unit_test.php`. Whereas, current;y, the local machine repo doesn't have any `test.php` file. So, how do I remove this file from Github repo as doing `git rm test.php` gives `No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you haven't made any further commits locally yet, I would back up and try again:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^         # revert index and tree one commit - to before the rename
git mv text.php unit_test.php  # rename file in a manner git can track
git commit                     # The rename should staged automatically
git push
```

Comment: Can I delete this particular local branch, do `checkout` and then do `git mv`? This will work I hope?

Comment: Yes. I did that (deleted the branch and again `checkout` that branch from `origin`) and it worked. I'll remember `git mv`. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to help. In my experience, `git` tends to have versions of most normal bash file-system commands (ls, mv, rm...)

Answer (score 0):

`git rm` tells git to not push a certain file from your computer to the repo, which you don't have on your computer anymore, so it gives you an error.

What you need to do is pull the repository first then `git rm test.php` and commit and push.